# Best Quiet Keyboard for video conference?

Tags: keyboards

I'm currently using Logitech G915 mechanic keyboard. But due to the pandemic we've many video meetings. The noise from G915 can be heard from other attendants so I got complained. I don't want to mute myself every time I try to search something during meeting.

Any suggestions for a quiet keyboard with good typing feedbacks?

### Requirements

1. Quiet
2. Backlit
3. Good Feedback
4. Preferably Black Color

So far, the closest one I can find is Logitech K740. I've tried Apple Keyboards but they don't have backlit, which is a deal breaker for me.

Comment: For mechanical keyboards, most of the sound is from the key caps bottoming out on the keyboard rather than key actuation itself (unless you've bought specific switches for that. I'm assuming you know which ones are your preference). A cheaper alternative may be just to [buy some O-rings](https://mechanicalkeyboardsplus.com/o-rings/) and see how that goes. Apparently some of the quieter switches just have rubber bits built in to dampen sound.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but if you have an Nvidia gpu I suggest checking out Nvidia broadcast. This is a pretty good noise filter. If it works well enough for you there would be no reason to buy a new keyboard in the first place :)